# Hexagonal lattice volume EOS fit

Tags: density-functional-theory, software, vasp

I have a little problem concerning hexagonal volume fitting using VASP.
I have followed these steps:

1. Relax the structure from a given volume using `ISIF =4`
2. Copy CONTCAR to POSCAR and relax it again
3. Run with `ISMEAR = -5` and without relaxation
4. Repeat for different volumes (+10% +5% 0% -5% -10%)
5. Use your script for EOS fitting.

It worked successfully with cubic systems. But for a hexagonal system (e.g. Carbon), I got the figure below. I don't know why I always get wrong results for the first volume point. Even with 7 volume points the first point always wrong.[image: Equation of state fitting]

Comment: What point in this figure is the first point? When you say its "wrong", what is your desired margin of error?

Comment: +1. Seems like a good question. I agree with Tyberius that the problem could be a little bit better described. As someone who doesn't work as much in this field, I'm not sure what the "correct" behavior should look like. Should it be monotonic (meaning the 3 points with smallest volume, are "wrong" here), or should it be somewhat flat (meaning that the point with ***largest*** volume here, is wrong)?

Comment: The correct points will give you parabolla-like curve, and as you see if I link all the points except the first one you'll get that curve.

Comment: I even tried with 5% 2.5% 0% -2.5% 5% and I got the same thing. Always the first point is wrong

Comment: I think the problem is that the variations are to high. Normally the cell variations are around 5-7%. Higher than that can be considered as deformations. (I just edited the firs comment).

Comment: How are you varying the volume? And by hexagonal carbon you mean graphite? Does the first point also have a low energy when you increase the volume slightly (e.g. make the first point 36 Å$^3$)? Finally, does still occur with a different hexagonal crystal (e.g. metallic Ti, $\beta$-quartz)?

Comment: The expected behavior should be parabolic for energy vs volume, which is what the OP is trying to say. Although I don't know the goal of this. Anyway, I would use ISIF = 2 to obtain energies. Another thing you could try is change a/b lattice constant sequentially instead of the volume if you can - i have had better success with it. If nothing works, maybe check if any of pymatgen's functions would help.

Comment: Kevein J.M, yes this is graphite, and I have obtained the the same problem for other hexagonal systems (e.g. WS2) , the first point always goes wrong and destroys the curve shape. I noticed something when I double calculate the energy of that points it gave me the good result. This really confused me.
gogo, I just have script for varying volume and fit to EOS. If you have a script for hexagonal systems lattices and fit to EOS please provide me with it.

Comment: Materials Project has many EOS fitted for hexagonal systems using VASP (e.g. https://www.materialsproject.org/materials/mp-79/#eqns-of-state) with the recipes for these EOS given in the atomate code, so you could check your method to those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, thanks to everyone who contributed to answer and discuss this question, your responses helped me to found the solution. Which is the vdW correction was missing in my calculations. Since that WS2 is a layered material, vdW interlayer correction must be added. So, I have added IVDW=10 in INCAR file to include the DFT-D2 method and this gaves me good results.

Answer (score 8):

Normally this should follow a nice equation of state (Rose, Murnigham etc.). I'd say the curve looks okay: $35 \mathrm{A}^3$ seems to be the questionable outlier.

There is not enough information on the setup here, but I will give two thoughts anyway:

1. Has the k-point convergence been tested?
2. HCP lattices require gamma centered k-point grids: https://cms.mpi.univie.ac.at/vasp/vasp/hexagonal_lattices.html

Answer (score 7):

There is little information in your question. It would be useful if you add your INCAR files. It seems to me that the problem could be in the fact that for such a cell there could be a “a free” parameter (c/a). So, you might be changing the volumen and the c/a ratio at the same time. Also, check that your are removing the density and wavefuncton files as a change in volumen changes the basis set